# How to install drivers for Belkin f9l1108tg wifi USB adapter?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I need help installing drivers for my Belkin f9l1108tg USB adapter.

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please identify your device from the terminal command: lsusb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions assume you are running the latest Ubuntu version and kernel 3.13.0-x; check:

```
uname -r
```

If it does not return 3.13.0-something, stop and tell us what it is. I'll amend the method accordingly.

Be certain the build tools are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Download this file to your desktop: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du/archive/kernel-version.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal; you may safely copy and paste these commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8192du-kernel-version
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

Your wireless should be working. You will have compiled the driver for your current kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, recompile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8192du-kernel-version
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```