# Using WiFi Dongle in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, usb, 15.10

I have a Belkin F9L1108-TG which supposedly uses the RTL8192DU driver.

The instructions here: [How to install drivers for Belkin f9l1108tg wifi USB adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499191/how-to-install-drivers-for-belkin-f9l1108tg-wifi-usb-adapter) do not work.

The instructions here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2153777&p=12688576#post12688576 have the following error on make

```
justin@Unicorn:~/Desktop/RTL8192DU Driver/rtl8192du$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-35-generic/build M=/home/justin/Desktop/RTL8192DU Driver/rtl8192du  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:138: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:669: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Driver/rtl8192du'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic'
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I'm not sure how to get past this.

FYI here's usb info

```
justin@Unicorn:~/Desktop/RTL8192DU Driver/rtl8192du$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components F9L1101v2 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8192DU]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git
cd rtl8192du
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

I have recommended that you install the latest version that I have tested through 'make' rather than correct your error on an unknown older version. The error is probably that there is a space in the name! `~/Desktop/RTL8192DU Driver`. You might be able to correct it by renaming the folder to: `~/Desktop/RTL8192DU_Driver`. I did not propose this at the outset, since I recommend that you use a later version from git.